# Jooq: How can I map a JSONB column to a Kotlin data class field?

Tags: kotlin, jackson, jooq

I have this table that has a `metadata` jsonb column, that's supposed to be a json array of data about other tables/PKs. I am able to insert rows into the database, but am having a hard time mapping the the record into the data class, due to this json column.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tracked_event
(
    id          uuid primary key,
    user_id     uuid references "user"      not null,
    -- other columns
    metadata jsonb not null
);
```

And I have a data class for it:

```
data class TrackedEvent(
    val id: UUID,
    val userId: UUID,
    // other fields
    val metadata: List<Metadata>
)

data class Metadata(
    val tableRef: String,
    val value: UUID
)
```

I can create a row just fine for it like so:

```
fun createTrackedEvent(trackedEvent: TrackedEvent): TrackedEvent {
        val record = dslContext.newRecord(TRACKED_EVENT, trackedEvent)
        record.metadata = JSONB.jsonb(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(trackedEvent.metadata))
        record.store()
        return record.into(TrackedEvent::class.java) // issue here
    }
```

However, that last line of code has a serializing issue:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: object is not an instance of declaring class; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: object is not an instance of declaring class (through reference chain: com.my.project.TrackedEvent["metadata"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["tableRef"])]
```

Note that if I change the data class to use an `Array` instead of a `List`, it works fine. But I think this should be able to work with the Kotlin's List instead?

```
data class TrackedEvent(
    val id: UUID,
    val userId: UUID,
    // other fields
    val metadata: Array<Metadata> // this works but then it asks me the following: Property with 'Array' type in a 'data' class: it is recommended to override 'equals()' and 'hashCode()' 
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to reach out to @Lukas Eder or someone from his Jooq team. If someone does, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to attach a `Converter` directly to your generated code as documented here:

- [Forced types](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/)
- [Jackson converters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-jackson-converter/) (this might work out of the box)

That way, the conversion from/to `JSONB` / `List<MetaData>` will be done transparently, whenever you access this information. Code generation configuration from the above documentation:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <forcedTypes>
        <forcedType>
          <userType><![CDATA[kotlin.Array<com.example.Metadata>]]></userType>
          <jsonConverter>true</jsonConverter>
          <includeExpression>(?i:tracked_event\.metadata)</includeExpression>
        </forcedType>         
      </forcedTypes>
    </database>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

See the docs for more details, and additional dependencies required.

Comment: Thanks, @Lukas Eder! That was very helpful! I'm gonna add another answer to this post to explain how I ended up fixing it

Comment: Hey @Lukas Eder, I have not been able to fetch data correctly, unfortunately. I've spent the entire day so far trying to work on this but have been stuck. I created a new question, and would really appreciate some input!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75488974/jooq-jsonconverter-not-converting-jsonb-into-list-of-class-when-fetching-data

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Because we don't use a `KotlinGenerator`, we have to use a `Metadata[]` instead: `<userType><![CDATA[com.example.Metadata[]]]></userType>`

This allows me to fetch data fine from a repo call like this:

```
fun findAllTrackedEvents(): List<TrackedEvent> {
        return dslContext.select(*TRACKED_EVENT.fields())
            .from(TRACKED_EVENT)
            .fetchInto(TrackedEvent::class.java)
    }
```

However, creating a row now no longer works as it appears the record model cannot be created from the data class model.

```
// error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.Metadata` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Metadata(tableRef=assessment, id=febe5f76-c25f-44f2-a501-c0b26e6fd173, extra=This is more data)')
 at [Source: (String)"["Metadata(table=assessment, id=febe5f76-c25f-44f2-a501-c0b26e6fd173, extra=This is more data)"]"; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0])

fun createTrackedEvent(trackedEvent: TrackedEvent): TrackedEvent {
        val record = dslContext.newRecord(TRACKED_EVENT, trackedEvent) // code fails on this line
//        record.metadata = JSONB.jsonb(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(trackedEvent.metadata))
        record.store()
        return record.into(TrackedEvent::class.java)
    }
```

---

Original:

The answer that @Lukas Eder provided me helped me get to the solution! I figured I'd expand on it a bit more here in case anyone came to this problem as well.

We generate Java class models in this project, so I was able to get this working by having the user type be the following:

```xml
<userType><![CDATA[java.util.List<com.example.Metadata>]]></userType>
```

Then in my Repository, I no longer have to map the metadata array to the jsonb:

```
fun createTrackedEvent(trackedEvent: TrackedEvent): TrackedEvent {
        val record = dslContext.newRecord(TRACKED_EVENT, trackedEvent)
        // record.metadata = JSONB.jsonb(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(trackedEvent.metadata)) // this is no longer needed! YAY :D
        record.store()
        return record.into(TrackedEvent::class.java)
    }

data class TrackedEvent(
    val id: UUID,
    val userId: UUID,
    // other fields
    val metadata: List<Metadata> // this stayed as a List instead of an array!
)
```