# Jooq: JsonConverter not converting jsonb into list of class when fetching data

Tags: kotlin, jackson, jooq

This is a continuation of a first question I asked here: [Jooq: How can I map a JSONB column to a Kotlin data class field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75478179/jooq-how-can-i-map-a-jsonb-column-to-a-kotlin-data-class-field)

Although I'm able to create new records just fine with the changes mentioned there, I'm not being able to fetch data like so:

```
fun findAllTrackedEvents(): List<TrackedEvent> {
        return dslContext.select(*TRACKED_EVENT.fields())
            .from(TRACKED_EVENT)
            .fetchInto(TrackedEvent::class.java)
    }
```

It seems that jackson is mapping the rows into LinkedHashMaps instead of mapping them into the fields of the `Metadata` data class. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: 

object is not an instance of declaring class; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
object is not an instance of declaring class (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.my.project.tracked_event.TrackedEvent["metadata"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["tableRef"])]
```

```
data class TrackedEvent(
    val id: UUID,
    // other fields
    val metadata: List<Metadata> // this metadata field in the database is of type jsonb
)

data class Metadata(
    val tableRef: String,
    val value: UUID
)
```

So it can convert the field properly when inserting but not when fetching?

Comment: Unlike the `Array<Metadata>` type, the `List<Metadata>` type is erased on the JVM, which is why I suggested using arrays, earlier. There's some magic possible in some cases using reflection, but I'm not sure what Jackson implements in that area. Can you try again with arrays?

Answer (score 0):

In my previous answer, [I suggested you use arrays instead of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75483426/521799). This had a reason. Consider this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val a: Array<Int?> = arrayOf(1)
    println(a::class.java)

    val b: List<Int?> = listOf(1)
    println(b::class.java)
}
```

It prints:

```
class [Ljava.lang.Integer;
class java.util.Collections$SingletonList
```

As you can see, while arrays are reified on the JVM, other generic types are not, and the `T` type variable of `List<T>` is erased. It is possible that Jackson cannot figure out the correct type to unmarshal at runtime using reflection, despite all the type information being available at compile time.

I would just use `Array<Metadata>` instead. Alternatively, of course, you can attach [a custom converter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/) to the column, instead of using the out of the box `<jsonConverter>`. That way, you're in full control of the mapping.

Comment: I initially tried that, but the (Java) record class that gets generated cannot resolve the import correctly:
`import kotlin.Array; // compiler error: Cannot resolve symbol 'Array'`

I might have a silly mistake in the custom converter I tried to create as well. I could not figure out how the overridden `toClass` function would work, as I don't know how to return a Class<List<Metadata>>

Comment: @LucasCosta: So, you're not using the `KotlinGenerator`? Then you have to generate `Metadata[]` as a type to make it valid Java code. You can't create a `Class<List<Metadata>>` in Java, as the `List<T>` type bound is erased. But you can cheat with raw types, e.g. `(Class) List.class`. But it would probably be better to ask new questions about this. The comment section is hard to use for complex topics.

Comment: right, before I joined this company, we were using jooq with a Java spring project. Kotlin was added on later, and (I'm not sure why) we never changed our record models to come from the `KotlinGenerator`. Idk if there's any downside to doing it now, but maybe something we could look into.

Comment: I used `Metadata[]` instead and that did the trick in the `pom.xml`:

`<userType><![CDATA[com.my.project.Metadata[]]]></userType>`

Now I can both create and fetch them. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @LucasCosta: There are some benefits of using `KotlinGenerator`. The downsides are, you can start bikeshedding jOOQ's stance on nullability (everything is nullable in SQL).

Comment: Ahh @Lukas Eder, I spoke too soon. I hadn't changed the data class to use a `List` instead of an Array. When changing that back, creating the row no longer works (the other issue I had created)

Comment: I used `Metadata[]`: `<userType><![CDATA[com.my.project.Metadata[]]]></userType>`

Fetching the data works here. But now that first question I had asked about creating the Metadata fails once again.

When creating a row in my repo `createTrackedEvent()` I get a `MismatchedInputException`: I can edit the first question to give extra context

Comment: I've edited this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75488092/8238895

Comment: @LucasCosta: This is getting messy and confusing across Stack Overflow questions and edits. I'm not sure if you have any remaining questions... Please note that the Stack Overflow guidelines recommend you don't ask questions in answers, or edit things that change the original meaning of a question / answer. Sometimes, it is best to start over again with a new question, showing again all the details that you have *at this point*.